# Does front-end JSS trial includes Sitecore Experience platform?

Tags: jss

It seems 60 day developer trial license is no longer available, and the only trial available is the front-end JSS trial. Does the front-end JSS trial includes Sitecore Experience platform?
Can I run my app in Connected dev mode? 
I didn't receive any login details in Developer Trial email but the link for 'Quick Start guide' which look like anyone can use it without any restriction. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until early 2020, the Developer Trial offered two modes: front-end and back-end. In reality, they were the same trial benefits (software download access/license file) but you were signing up for a different learning path. The trial flow would send you appropriate messages on content you should look into personalized to your choice of trial.

As of the changes in early 2020 (and up until the time of this answer in May 2020) there is now one mode for the Developer Trial: Front-end (JSS). We are updating the learning flow to be headless/disconnected, and we now offer a sandbox in Azure instead of a license file, along with disconnected learning. You still gain access to download the software to learn on your own if you have your own license file.

Currently, we don't have the capability to offer the same headless learning for .NET developers, but it is on our backlog.

To your questions:

1. **Does the trial include Experience Platform?**
   Yes, it does. The Connected learning portion of the trial allows you to connect to a Sitecore Experience Platform instance and learn about using JSS in Connected mode, leveraging some of the features of XP. You also have download access to access anything on dev.sitecore.net.
2. **Can I run my app in Connected dev mode?** There are no limitations in the trial on how you approach your learning, but the intended path is to learn Disconnected first so you can understand the JSS basics and then move to a Connected learning path.
3. **Anybody can access the quick start?** That is correct. Just like the jss.sitecore.com, we have put no gates on getting access to the information about how to get started learning. That is where you should start. The trial will provide you with additional benefits other than the quick start.
4. **Login details missing** There is currently a step whereby we need to authorize and add you to the sandbox requesting environment. You do not receive the credentials immediately. Once you are setup in the system you should be sent a message informing you that you can request your Azure instance for Connected learning. Note that it is a very limited access sandbox.